# In Rails, how would you merge these two different has_manys into one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

Let's say we have a User.

A user has_many documents through account like so…

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :documents, :through => :account, :order => "created_at DESC"
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owner, :class_name => "User", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :documents, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Nice and simple, this is where it gets tricky…

A user can also collaborate on documents, this via the collaborators join table…

```
class Collaborator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :documnet
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collaborators, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :collaborators
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collaborators, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

The final user bit of this is what i'm not sure about. I want to add another has many documents, and when you call user.documents it blends both documents via their account and the ones they're collaborating on…

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :documents, :through => :account, :order => "created_at DESC"

  #documents need to do both has manys…
  has_many :collaborators, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :documents, :through => :collaborators
end
```

Thanks, it's a bit long but I can think of a neat solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method that will request on the tables `documents`, `accounts` and `collaborators` to find the documents related to the user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #...

  def documents
    Document.includes(:account, :collaborators).where('collaborators.user_id = ? OR documents.account_id = ?', self.id, self.account.id)
  end

end
```

I've not tested this request, but I hope you get the idea. Please correct it if it's erroneous.

For the 2 `has_many documents, :through...`, you can remove them if you don't need them anymore; Otherwise, you have to give them different names (and different from the method above).

Comment: Thanks! I modified it a bit to make it work, add my changes. Cheers.